# cygwin64 scons version issue

Tags: cygwin

Cygwin currently provides two versions of `scons` package in its built-in package library: 2.3.4-1 and 2.4.0-1.
(https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/scons-src.html)

However, I am now trying to compile an external C++ library with Cygwin terminal on Windows platform. After following certain tutorial, I have run into the issue shown below.

```
$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Using Python version: 2.7.18

Using gcc version 10.2.0

SCons 2.4.1 or greater required, but you have SCons 2.4.0
```

Now the problem is that Scons 2.4.0 is the newest version in Cygwin's built-in package library. So is there a way that I can download a newer version of `scons` separately and add it to the path under cygwin manually?

Many thanks for any information about this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cygwin package has been updated to 4.1.0, the last one, that uses python 3.8

https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/scons.html

give some time to the package to propagate to the mirrors and than you can upgrade

Comment: Thank you for your work and I have successfully compiled the target library. However, there is an interesting problem worth further investigation. In my case, I directly updated the scons and corresponding python packages by rerun the cygwin setup program, and it works. But I also found that if one starts from scratch and directly chooses scons 4.1.0 in their first installation of cygwin, an error message will pop out during the installation:

Comment: `The following package(s) had downloaded errors: python2-2.7.15-1`. This means one can only choose scons 2.4.0 in their first installation to avoid errors.

Comment: Current python2 on Cygwin is 2.7.18-4

Comment: Yeah I know it indeed is, but in my case that is the exact error message. Just want to clarify that by choosing scons version 2.4.0 during the first installation and then update it to 4.1.0 later I can circumvent this error.